# Checking a box based on criteria in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have my checkbox "checked" when my user clicks Yes when validating approvals. The checkbox column lives in the retailEntry table but I added it to my approval query so they should be linked.

The problem is that all "pack_numbers" are checked even the ones not present on the approval query. I want only the packs that appear on the approvalqry to be checked. It appears I cannot "Check" the "Creative Approval" from the approvalqry  and if I use the retailentry recordset it just checks everything.

Any advice or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
Set rap = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Approvalqry")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("RetailEntry")
On Error Resume Next
If Not (rap.EOF And rap.BOF) Then
rap.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    If rap.RecordCount > 0 Then
        nConfirmation = MsgBox("PackNumber " & rap.Fields("Pack_Number") & " Offer " & rap.Fields("Catid") & " is currently in the Proofing Stage, and will require Approval from CMS - Creative, and Divisional Merch Manager. Confirm Approvals have been received?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Approval Required!")
        If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
        

        'Update approved checkbox
         If rap.Fields("Pack_Number").Value Then
            rap.Edit
            rap![Creative Approval] = True
            rap.Update
         Else
         End If
    
        Else
        MsgBox "Please obtain Late Retail Change Approval for this product within Offer " & rap.Fields("Catid") & ", then resubmit your request."
        ClearTables
        End
        End If
    End If
rap.MoveNext
rst.MoveNext
rs.MoveNext
Me.Requery
Loop
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Err.Clear
```

Comment: Add a Boolean field to your table and bind the checkbox to this.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav I'll do some digging on that.

Comment: If data source for Approvalqry is RetailEntry, why is it not editable? Edit question to show its SQL statement. `If rap.Fields("Pack_Number").Value Then` expects a True/False result. I doubt Pack_Number is a true/false field. Unless these two recordsets have the exact same set of records in same order, need to do a FindFirst on rap to locate record associated with the rs record, not do a loop on rap. I am not sure what Gustav is recommending since you say you already have a 'checkbox' in RetailEntry table.

Comment: @June7 this is exactly what I stumbled into as I was working through the problem. Issue is resolved :)

Comment: @June7: I got confused by _if I use the retailentry recordset it just checks everything_.

Comment: @June7 yeah I was very tired and after relooking over my logic I realized that was what was happening and thats when I stumbled in the same solution you suggested since it made more sense to update outside of the loop. :) Really appreciate the help!